# Swap multiple column in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, swap

SUppose I have a data frame

```
data=data.frame(X1_C1=c(1:5),
                X2_C1=c(11:15),
                X3_C1=c(111:115),
                X1_C2=c(2:6),
                X2_C2=c(21:25),
                X3_C2=c(211:215),
                X1_C3=c(3:7),
                X2_C3=c(31:35),
                X3_C3=c(311:315))


> data
  X1_C1 X2_C1 X3_C1 X1_C2 X2_C2 X3_C2 X1_C3 X2_C3 X3_C3
1     1    11   111     2    21   211     3    31   311
2     2    12   112     3    22   212     4    32   312
3     3    13   113     4    23   213     5    33   313
4     4    14   114     5    24   214     6    34   314
5     5    15   115     6    25   215     7    35   315
```

I would like to swap the value so columns in variable ending with `_C2` and `_C3`. For example,  swap `X1_C2` and `X1_C3`, `X2_C2` and `X2_C3` and similar for other `Xs` in `C2` and `C3`

Any help in appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to swap columns (not just the names), you can try the code below

```
> data[c(matrix(names(data), 3)[, c(1, 3, 2)])]
  X1_C1 X2_C1 X3_C1 X1_C3 X2_C3 X3_C3 X1_C2 X2_C2 X3_C2
1     1    11   111     3    31   311     2    21   211
2     2    12   112     4    32   312     3    22   212
3     3    13   113     5    33   313     4    23   213
4     4    14   114     6    34   314     5    24   214
5     5    15   115     7    35   315     6    25   215
```

If you want to swap the names

```
> setNames(data, c(matrix(names(data), 3)[, c(1, 3, 2)]))
  X1_C1 X2_C1 X3_C1 X1_C3 X2_C3 X3_C3 X1_C2 X2_C2 X3_C2
1     1    11   111     2    21   211     3    31   311
2     2    12   112     3    22   212     4    32   312
3     3    13   113     4    23   213     5    33   313
4     4    14   114     5    24   214     6    34   314
5     5    15   115     6    25   215     7    35   315
```

Comment: What if I want to swap the values only, not the column name?

Comment: What do you mean @Uddin?  If you don't want to change column name, a simple reordering of columns will do.  Amazing answer as always TIC, upvoted already

Answer (score 2):

a `dplyr` approach, not as good as TIC has suggested, but if it may help

```
data %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., '_C2', '_CC3'), ends_with('_C2')) %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., '_C3', '_C2'), ends_with('_C3')) %>%
  rename_with(~str_replace(., '_CC3', '_C3'), ends_with('_CC3'))

  X1_C1 X2_C1 X3_C1 X1_C3 X2_C3 X3_C3 X1_C2 X2_C2 X3_C2
1     1    11   111     2    21   211     3    31   311
2     2    12   112     3    22   212     4    32   312
3     3    13   113     4    23   213     5    33   313
4     4    14   114     5    24   214     6    34   314
5     5    15   115     6    25   215     7    35   315
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the columns names?

```
tmp1=grepl("_C2",colnames(data))
tmp2=grepl("_C3",colnames(data))

colnames(data)[tmp1]=gsub("_C2","_C3",colnames(data)[tmp1])
colnames(data)[tmp2]=gsub("_C3","_C2",colnames(data)[tmp2])
```